# Thrift to JSON and vice versa

Tags: json, thrift

I am working on Apache thrift these days. I have some .thrift file schemas. I wanted to convert them into JSON files. Is there any open source library or tool which can do that?
Similarly for JSON to thrift also, if there is any library or tool, please do let me know?

Comment: May I ask what's the point of it? The Thrift compiler only consumes Thrift IDL (not "*schema*") files. There is no JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form that would satisfy your otherwise very unspecific request would be this:

```
{
   "IDL" : "<your thrift IDL blob here>"
}
```